# Changing Symbol/Marker Outline Width in Julia Using PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, line, marker, outline

I'm trying to change the outline of the symbol (marker) inside a scatter plot in Julia using the PyPlot backend.  I've tried `edgecolor`, `edgewidth`, `edgelinewidth`, `markercolor`, `markerwidth`, `markerlinewidth` and a variety of other key/values from various sources, but Julia/PyPlot recognizes none of these.  How do I change the outline of the symbol/marker in a scatter plot executed in Julia using the PyPlot backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia using the PyPlot backend, the correct key to manipulate the symbol/marker outline is `markerstroke...`.  For example, `markerstrokewidth=1` sets the outline of the marker to 1px, while `markerstrokecolor="red"` sets the outline color of the marker to red.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in 2022, PyPlot in Julia has completely changed. To change the edge size, the keyword is `linewidths`. In general, the repl is the best way to get up to date info. Just type `?` (to get the help prompt), then `PyPlot.scatter`.